# Complete (?) list of row reduction applications

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I continue to be amazed that *row reduction* is still, by far, the single most useful technique I've learned for solving linear algebra problems. Even as I do practice problems for my qualifying exam, my first thought is, "Is there something I can row reduce?" So I thought it might be fun/interesting to come up with something like a "complete" list of applications for row reduction, and I'd like to ask if you have anything to add!

Here's what I've got:

**Basic Applications**

1. Find a basis for the row space
2. Find a basis for the span of a set of vectors
3. Find a basis for the column space (i.e. range of a transformation)
4. Find the rank of a matrix
5. Find a basis for the null space
6. Solve $Ax = 0$
7. Solve $Ax = b$
8. Find the inverse of a matrix
9. Calculate $\det A$
10. Check if a set of vectors is linearly independent

**Advanced or Niche Aplications**

11. Compute the LU, LDU, or LDL decompositions of a matrix
12. Per [*Linear Algebra Done Wrong*](https://www.math.brown.edu/streil/papers/LADW/LADW.html), diagonalize the matrix of a quadratic form
13. For symmetric/Hermitian matrices, find the number of each positive, negative, and zero eigenvalue (as these match the signs of the pivots)
14. By extension of 13, test if a symmetric/Hermitian matrix is positive definite
15. Per *Hoffman and Kunze,* showing that the characteristic polynomial equals the minimal polynomial of a companion matrix.
16. Per *Hoffman and Kunze,* one can use row reduction (and properties of multilinear functions) to show that $\det \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & C \end{bmatrix} = \det A \det C$ for the block matrix

It is applications like the last six that I am looking to add to this list (or basic applications that I have missed). I have done a lot of googling, but unfortunately one finds dozens of sources aimed at very new linear algebra students, and I thought maybe Stack could supply some interesting/surprising/advanced applications I hadn't thought of! Thanks for your input!

Comment: Actually 6) is a special case of 7) when you take b = 0. You need to retain only distinct applications.. Also, 10) is a deduction that can be made from 4) when you find the rank of a matrix. Det value in 9) also conveys whether the row vectors are linearly independent or not. 10) is not a new application, I feel.

Comment: I don't see why 'Hoffman and Kunze' are cited for 15) and 16) as these are well-known facts and proved in many text books on linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another non-listed case:

The computation of a product of the form $CA^{-1}B$ where $C,A,B$ have resp. dimensions $(m \times n), \ \ (n \times n), \ \ (n \times p).$

(such a product occurs in particular for the computation of a [Schur  complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement))

This computation is done by Gaussian elimination on the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ -C & 0\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}A' & B' \\ 0 & D'\end{pmatrix}$$

using operations "zeroing" the first $n$ columns below $A$ giving $D'=CA^{-1}B$.

Reference: Lemma 10.6 p. 269 of "Fundamental Problems of Algorithmic Algebra" by Chee Keng Yap, Oxford University Press, 2000.

Comment: Thank you! Reminds me also of a proof of the number 16 I listed. I would bet there is a wealth of row reduction applications where matrices or tensors are assembled into block matrices and row reduced!

Comment: For sure. I would like to add that, rather often, row or column reduction techniques are well understood with equivalent matrix factorizations like LU or PLU, QR...